# Leaflet Layer Visibility Checkbox

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openlayers, layers

I have created this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhubbL7m/9/) **OpenLayers** map that toggles the layers visibility using the bootstrap-switch.

I am looking to achieve the same with leaflet but can't seem to get the equivalent of the setVisible command in Leaflet to work with the bootstrap-switch.

[This JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/nhubbL7m/12/) also includes the Leaflet version that doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried `layer.hide()` function?

Comment: @muzaffar yes but not got it to work with the switch

Comment: can you make a fiddle of leaflet case as well where it is not working?

Comment: @muzaffar here you go: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/nhubbL7m/12/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Leaflet, in order to remove a layer from map, use this function

```
map.removeLayer(layer_source);
```

And If you want to add the same layer again, use this

```
map.addLayer(layer_source);
```

I've made a copy of your fiddle and [here is working fiddle for your case](https://jsfiddle.net/zafrii/x36qkk3c/)

Comment: Work perfectly, cheers @muzaffar

Comment: Alas, five years later, this fiddle no longer works :-(